# Select Previous row date as current row date

Tags: sql

I have a Table like below
[image]
I need it as below
[image]

Group by CardNo and when insured id is different BirthDate should be previous row End_Date
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the logic and provide a database tag.

Comment: Grouped by Card_No. when insured id is different from previous row, Birth_Date should be previous row End_Date

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
select card_no, 
    insured_no, 
    lag(end_date, 1, birth_date) over (partition by card_no order by end_date, birth_date) as birth_date,
    end_date
from table_name
```

Have to pass (end_date, 1, birth_date) in **lag**, otherwise, birth_date for the first row will not be correct as you need the same birth_date for the first row.

Comment: Thanks ,I have updated output table pic. please check and guide me to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`. It is not very clear which column(s) can be used to order the records, but the idea is:

```
select card_no, insured_no, 
    lag(end_date, 1, birth_date) over(partition by card_no order by insured_no) birth_date,
    end_date
from mytable
```

Ideally, you would replace `insured_no` in the `order by` clause with a column (or a set of columns) that uniquely identifies the position of each row.

Comment: Thanks ,I have updated output table pic. please check and guide me to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because of the duplicates.  I would start with `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(end_date) over (partition by card_no order by end_date, birth_date) as col
from t;
```

However, the results are unstable and would be better if there were a unique id on each row.

Comment: Thanks ,I have updated output table pic. please check and guide me to achieve it